# Jump Point Search on an infinite grid

Tags: path-finding

I recently found Jump Point Search and it seems like a really interesting algorithm. But I wonder about what its performance is like when your grid is of infinite size. When searching diagonally, is it not possible that the orthogonal rays being sent out can go on for an arbitrarily long amount of time on an infinite grid even if the place you want to pathfind to is just a few steps away? Is JPS feasible in general for such grids?

Comment: Hint: any algorithm you perform on an "infinite" grid isn't really done exhaustively on an infinite grid (since that would take infinite time!) It's done on a "big enough" *part* of the grid for the question you need to answer. So, your first step is to identify: what's "big enough" for your particular needs, or what's a logical way to define the *part* that's relevant to your question? What constraints can you apply to limit how much of your space you consider at a time?

Comment: @DMGregory Thanks. I've given some thought to it and maybe the right thing to do is to modify the algorithm to stop the rays if the total distance from the origin is over a certain value. The only question is, what should I do once I decide that the search should stop? Do I need to place forced neighbors along the rays? I'll have to think about how this will work specifically for JPS.

Comment: Try telling us more about the game feature you're hoping to use Jump Point Search to support, and the type of game content it's running on (like how you populate your map). This might help us fight appropriate ways to limit the search, or give it a sensible bottom-out case.